# Html Link with header?

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc, token

everyone

I'm fresh to the front-end and .net MVC. Recently, I am trying to develop the login system to a website and facing some problem when developing links to another page.

For example, I have two page, A and B. A has a link that can jump to B. However, since I have to confine the access, I put the authentication in B's controller. like this.

```
[Authorization]
public class BController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

As you see, without authentication, no one is able to get B's view. The way it exams the authority is via checking the the header, which I put token in.

So, my question becomes how to code html link when it need to jump to a authenticated page. Currently, the link is in this kind of form.

```
<h2>@Html.ActionLink("B page", "Index", "B")</h2>
```

I've already known that this is just a helper and that it can be transformed into a simple html. Still, I am confused how to use html link to jump to a new page with token.

Does anyone have any experience like this?

thanks million times.

Comment: Have you authenticated with a user?

Comment: well, it should process both of two situation. Currently, when user login, I will send a token to him. So, all I need is when he clicks the hyperlink of page B, the front-end need to request server with that token. Howerver, I just don't understand how to do that with a link tag.

Answer (score 0):

A Hyperlink generated with `ActionLink` or pure html anchor tag will do a `GET` request. `Get` request will not have any connection to the html you write. It is just a Url with query strings. Thats all that matters to navigate to a page.

Coming back to your authorization filter, if the users are not already authenticated when on page A and if  they click the link to page B then they should be sent to the login page with a `ReturnUrl` parameter. After successfully login they should be redirected to the `ReturnUrl` (which would be page B in your case).

On the other hand, if the users are already loged-in than the Asp.net MVC framework will evaluate that and allow the users to go to page B from page A.

All of the above will require an working authentication process. You could start with `Form authentication` that comes with Asp.net MVC project templates. That is usually enough to deal with any basic authentication and authorization.

Comment: Thanks lots. After reviewing your reply, there comes another question. How should I jump to new page with token? in fact, I've done the authentication part. Now, it can redirect to login page when authenticating failed. I know how to use fetch or ajax to get view but I don't know how to use that view to renew whole page.

Comment: What token are you talking about? If it is the Form authentication then when you redirect to a new page the cookie based tokens get sent automatically with the request. Also what do you mean by 'renew whole page'?

Comment: I am using JWT. when the user login, I put the token in their cookie. I am surprised by  Form authentication. I really wonder how does it send cookie while renew page. Do you have any reference of what it really does? I think that it is still use js and html but i can't figure out how it achieve that.

Comment: btw, renewing whole page means that it jumps to new page and show different address above.